# Caffe - Forward multiple images through a net in parallel

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

How exactly would one do this. Right now, I have to iterate through each image and forward it. I would like to know if I can set multiple images at once and forward them through

```
for f in fnames:
    i+=1
    print i,"/",len(fnames), f
    img = Image.open(f)
    # scale all images to 256x256
    img = img.resize((256,256), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = numpy.array(img).astype(numpy.float32)

    transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', img)
    #print transformed_image.shape

    # use CNN to predict (but don't use predicted class)
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformed_image

    output = net.forward()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by putting all images into a single batch and then running `net.forward()` once for the entire batch.

```
bs = len(fnames)  # batch size
in_shape = net.blobs['data'].data.shape
in_shape[0] = bs # set new batch size
net.blobs['data'].reshape(*in_shape)
net.reshape()
for i, f in enumerate(fnames):
    img = Image.open(f)
    # scale all images to 256x256
    img = img.resize((256,256), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = numpy.array(img).astype(numpy.float32)

    transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', img)
    #print transformed_image.shape

    # put the image into i-th place in batch
    net.blobs['data'].data[i,:,:,:] = transformed_image   

# after reading all images into batch, forward once:
net.forward()
```

Comment: I just tried to do that..but unfortunately, it seems the size of my net is fixed at 10. (10, 3, 224, 224)

Comment: reshaping would not work here. The 3,244,244 part refers to the RGB image. 10 refers to N images. Do you mean i somehow append/modify the net object?

Comment: @Raaj yes. change 10 to the number of input images

Comment: Hmm..is this..allowed? Is there a particular reason the program was set as 10. Might I run out of GPU memory etc?

Comment: @Raaj you might. changing the batch size for test is legitimate

Comment: I just tested this and it does not work:

bs = 20
in_shape = net.blobs['data'].data.shape
in_shape = (bs, in_shape[1], in_shape[2], in_shape[3])

#print in_shape
#fag
net.blobs['data'].reshape(in_shape)
net.reshape()

TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type int from this Python object of type tuple

Comment: I tried doing the reshape on the data element (net.blobs['data'].reshape(in_shape)), but it says it cannot reshape:  cannot reshape array of size 1505280 into shape (20,3,224,224)

Comment: @Raaj glad I could help :)

Comment: are you familiar with the OpenCV DNN library, i am trying to figure out how to pass multiple images into that too.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html

Comment: @Raaj I am not familiar with that library. Consider post a new question with proper tags.